# Exception when inserting row to database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've written this code to insert a row into the database:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["earchConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
//string insCmd = "Insert into [node] (title, parent_id, oid, display, linkById, customLinks, contentType) values (@title, @parent_id, @oid, @display, @linkById, @customLinks, @contentType)";
string insCmd = "Insert into [node] (title) values (@title)";
SqlCommand insertUser = new SqlCommand(insCmd, con);
insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", TextBoxTitle.Text);

try
{
    insertUser.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    Response.Redirect("addNode.aspx");
    Label1.Text = "update success";

}
catch (Exception er)
{
    Label1.Text = er.StackTrace;
}
```

The stack trace:

```
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.GetOpenConnection(String method)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ValidateConnectionForExecute(String method, SqlCommand command)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ValidateCommand(String method, Boolean async)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
at Admin_addNode.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
in c:\inetpub\web1\Admin\addNode.aspx.cs:line 52
```

Anyone know what's the problem?

Comment: Can we have the exception type and message as well as the stack trace?

Comment: _"Anyone know what's the problem?"_ - yes, you've got to set a breakpoint in your `catch` clause and look up the exception. Now you only print the stack trace, which is relevant, but doesn't show the actual exception. Set a breakpoint, inspect the exception and search the web for it. If you then can't find a solution, ask a question on how to solve it, showing what you have tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

call `con.Open()` first before executing `ExecuteNonQuery()`

```
con.Open();
insertUser.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: you're welcome @hkinterview! btw, programmers also need to sleep :D

Comment: @MahmoudGamal now you know :D even computer sleeps. hehe